# How to enter multiple user defined values on data Refresh in Business Objects

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to run a Business Objects report in 5.1.9.

When I refresh the report it asks me in a box labelled "Enter and Select Values"

I can either enter a single free text value in the text box or I can type % to leave it unfiltered.

I would like to specify several values in this box rather than one or all. How do I do this? I have looked everywhere on google but perhaps I have the wrong search terms?

Answer (score 0):

Wow - 5.1.9 almost 15 years old.

The box you're seeing is a **prompt**.  Prompts can be defined either in the report's query, or in a universe object that's used in the query.

If it's defined in the query, then it's easy to change.  Open up the query panel via Data -> Edit Data Provider (assuming you're using Full Client, WebI is a little different).  You'll see the query panel with result object in the top-right pane and conditions in the lower-right pane.  Look for a condition that includes the text you see in the prompt.  That condition will likely have an "Equal To" operator.  Change that to "In List", and the prompt should then accept multiple values.

If the prompt is not present in the conditions pane, then it is most likely applied via a universe object.  If you want to make this change for this report only, you *could* modify the query's SQL (but only if you're using Full Client; for WebI, you'd need to modify the universe as described below).  Hit the SQL button, and you will see the generated SQL.  First, check off the "Do not generate SQL" checkbox in the lower-left of the dialog.  Not doing so will cause your changes to be lost.  Look through the SQL for a `@prompt()` function.  Within that function, you should see `mono` -- change that to `multi`, and close the panel.

If you don't want to change the query's SQL, or if you want the change to apply to all reports, then you will need to modify the universe object that produces the prompt.  You will need to access to Designer, and permission to import/export the universe.  You will also need to locate the object that produces the prompt.  Once you do, change `mono` to `multi` as described above, and export the universe.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried entering either of the following?

"FreeText1";"FreeText2";"FreeText3"

or

"FreeText1","FreeText2","FreeText3"

(obvs replacing FreeText with whatever your strings are)